# Phaser CE "shuffle" method on Tilemap isn't working

Tags: shuffle, phaser-framework, tile

It shuffles the tiles around but the 'properties' set in the JSON remain in the same place, so the tiles look shuffled but their properties are now out of place. Is there a way around this? I need each tile to retain all of its properties regardless of where it gets placed.